# FCM foreground notification Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException error

Tags: firebase, asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to receive the message but only display in the log. I wanted to display as a notification at the top of the screen.

Here is my code:
MainActivity.cs

```
static readonly string TAG = "MainActivity";
internal static readonly string CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel";
internal static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            CreateNotificationChannel();
            CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token));
}

void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                                                  "FCM Notifications",
                                                  NotificationImportance.Default)
            {

                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

In `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class

```
[Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);
            SendNotification(body, message.Data);
        }

        void SendNotification(string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
            {
                intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
            }

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
                                                          MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                          intent,
                                                          PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                                      .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

I can received the message in here: `Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);` and it will log the body of the message however after calling the `SendNotification` function, then in this line:

```
var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

It will have error: `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`

Where can I am getting the value for `CHANNEL_ID` and `NOTIFICATION_ID`? Currently, it has value: my_notification_channel and 100 respectively as same as in the docs. Is this the reason why I'm having this error?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a problem with the Notification construction

```
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification) //you could not commen it
                                  .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                                  .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                  .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**SetSmallIcon** is a required parameter, otherwise you will build an error